# How to register a bean in Quarkus Main method

Tags: java, dependency-injection, javabeans, quarkus

I have a Quarkus application that works in batch mode. I have a QuarkusMain class, with a method that implements QuarkusApplication interface.

That method is a static method, so I'm not able to inject Beans because they have a null value.

What is the way to inject Beans in Quarkus from a static method in a QuarkusMain class?

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you really after creating beans in the static method, or more just after how to startup Quarkus ?

In main method the only thing you need to do is call `Quarkus.run(YourMain.class, args);` which then will make YourMain class a bean and in here allow @Inject.

You can also use picocli which also ends up with a class you can use @Inject.

Example of that I have here: https://github.com/jbangdev/jbang-catalog/blob/master/catalog2readme.java

Comment: Thanks @Max Rydahl Andersen my question is how to startup Quarkus with QuarkusMain and then how to inject beans, but I don't know that YourMain.class will make a bean, so thank you for your response!

Answer (score 1):

You can use Arc class in this way:

Annotate your beans with a @Startup annotation.
https://quarkus.io/guides/lifecycle#startup_annotation

Then, in your static method:

```
YourBean yourBean = Arc.container().instance(YourBean.class).get();
```